# Dojo dgrid dstore collection - "or" filter not working

Tags: collections, dojo, filtering, dgrid, dstore

I'm working with Dojo dgrid and I have problem with dstore filtering with using "or" statement.

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

var start_date= new Date();
start_date.setDate(today.getDate() - 5);
start_date.setHours(0,0,0,0); 

grid.set('collection', store.filter(
    new store.Filter().or(
            new store.Filter().gte('datefield1', start_date).lte('datefield1',today),
            new store.Filter().gte('datefield2', start_date).lte('datefield2',today)
    )
));
```

Both conditions works perfect when they are separatelly, but when I put them together into "or" filter it works like "and" statement: both have to be "true" to return values.

How to make "or" statement to work properly in dojo dgrid dstore?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by **kfranqueiro** from SitePen on their GitHub. 
Really Big thanks for his involvement.

```
store.filter(function (item) {
    return (item.datefield1 >= start_date && item.datefield1 <= today) ||
        (item.datefield2 >= start_date && item.datefield2 <= today);
});
```

Full discussion:
https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/1265

Comment: Ken always comes to the rescue! :D